# Where does the 'event' param come from in javascript event handlers?

Tags: javascript, events, function, parameters, handler

Often I see javascript code where event handlers (like onmousemove) are assigned dynamically.
Example:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onmousemove = function(e)
{ /* do some stuff with event e */ }
```

Apparently this 'e' parameter is some kind of event object. Where does that come from, as in: who or what defines what this 'e' parameter is when the function is called, and can I also do this in static html?
I mean like this:

```
<div id='foo' onmousemove='Bla(e)'> ... </div>
```

What should I fill in for 'e' to get that same event thing? And can I also combine that with more parameters, like

```
<div id='foo' onmousemove='Bla(this,e,4)'> ... </div>
```

where e is, again, supposed to be the event object?

Comment: I believe it's a reference to `window.event` that is passed to your callback event handler.

Comment: Right, yes, thanks, just found out something similar by accident. It seems I can use window.event inside my own event handlers (even the ones set in html, i.e. not necessarily a function(e) kind of function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event object is stored in `window.event` inside of any event handler, so you do not need to worry about your handler conforming to accepting it as a parameter.

In your second and third examples, the `e` parameter will be passed as undefined because no variable `e` exists in that scope (unless you have a global `e`).

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers are defined as `callback` methods. A callback is (hence the expression) called from another process at a later time. This is done by the environment (the browser in this case) at the time an event fires.

it calls your callback function and passes in the `event object`.

Comment: OK thanks, so by definition, when assigning an event handler function dynamically (i.e. in code), it will assume it's a one-parameter function with the parameter being the event object? And is there also a way to get that event object in 'static' event handlers, I mean the ones that are set in html (like my 2 div examples).

Comment: @SheldonPinkman: yes its defined so. And no, you cannot access the event object without a function.

Comment: OK Thanks! Oh and I accidentally found out that window.event seems to contain the event (at least that seems to work in a static event handler). Anyway, that callback stuff is now clear to me, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as a callback method. The event is initially created by the operating system, sent to the web browser, which then passes it off to you in javascript Event object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the event is an object instance of ActionEvent. I don't think ActionEvent can be manually instantiated, so you can't do it in static HTML. Even if it would be possible, it certainly wouldn't be best practice.