# Can someone explain how this parameter is able to get a value?

Tags: javascript, parameters

```
getWeatherData();
function getWeatherData(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((success) => {
            console.log(success)
        })
    }
```

It returns an object with lat, long and other info, but how? Success is literally a parameter and has no value, right? It's not defined anywhere and I didn't pass a value in when I invoked the function.

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: `.getCurrentPosition()` executes the anonymous function `(success) => { ... }` and passes it the location of the user/browser (the object with lat, long, ...) to it as argument.

Comment: Similar topic about callback parameters: [What exactly is the parameter e (event) and why pass it to JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35936365) | [Where does the 'event' param come from in javascript event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9925947)

Answer (score 3):

Function parameters get values when the function is **called**.

You are passing a function (lets call it *anon*) as an argument to `getCurrentPosition`.

`getCurrentPosition` (which you did not write and which you are not looking at the source code of) or a function that it passes *anon* onto will, at some point, call it. At that point *anon* is passed arguments.